# NodeJS Redis (ioredis) hgetall throwing undefined error

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I am building a NodeJS app that connects to a Redis cluster using the ioredis module.

Overview of the issue:

- A lookup query for a key that doesn't exist in the cache returns an empty object as expected
- A lookup query for a key that DOES exist cache is throwing an error but the error is undefined.

I created a controller to create and manage the connection:

```
const redis = require('ioredis');
const consoleLogger = require('../logger/logger.js').console;

const redisCtrl = {};

redisCtrl.defaultPrefix = 'lookup:';

// Local variable to store the full time connection to Redis for lookups
let _redisClient;

// Redis connection config
redisCtrl.redisConnect = {
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD
};

// Redis config
redisCtrl.redisConfig = {
  dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
  redisOptions: {
    tls: process.env.REDIS_SSL === 'false' ? false : true,
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    maxRetriesPerRequest: 1
  }
};

// Retrieve the redis connection
redisCtrl.redisClient = async () => {
  if (!_redisClient) {
    _redisClient = await redisCtrl.getNewConnect();
  }
  return _redisClient;
}

redisCtrl.getNewConnect = async () => {
  let makeConnection;

  if (process.env.REDIS_CLUSTER === 'true') {
    makeConnection = new redis.Cluster([redisCtrl.redisConnect], redisCtrl.redisConfig);
  } else {
    makeConnection = new redis(redisCtrl.redisConnect);
  }

  makeConnection.on("connect", function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      consoleLogger.info("REDIS connected");
    } else {
      consoleLogger.info("REDIS connection error");
      consoleLogger.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  });

  makeConnection.on("error", function (error) {
    consoleLogger.info("REDIS error");
    consoleLogger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    throw new Error(error);
  });

  return makeConnection;
}

redisCtrl.closeInstance = (cb) => {
  if (_redisClient) {
    _redisClient.quit(cb);
  }
}

module.exports = redisCtrl;
```

This works to establish the connection.

However, when attempting to get a result, an empty error is thrown from the hgetall method.

```
/**
 * Lookup asset by assetId in Redis cache
 * Return asset data object
 * @param {str} assetId
 */
assetsCtrl.lookupByAssetId = async (assetId) => {
  // Prepend default cache prefix to lookup value
  const lookupKey = `${redisPrefix || `lookup:`}${assetId}`;
  let cachedAsset;
  try {
    cachedAsset = await assetsCtrl.redisClient.hgetall(lookupKey);
  } catch (e) {
    consoleLogger.error(`Lookup by assetId failed. Lookup key: ${lookupKey}`);
    consoleLogger.error(e);
    throw new Error(e);
  }
  return cachedAsset;
}
```

The error is thrown but the error is undefined. The "catch" block of the `redisClient.hgetall(lookupKey)` line is getting called but the error is not defined.

```
error: Lookup by assetId failed. Lookup key: lookup:test123456789
**error: undefined {"command":{"name":"hget","args":["lookup:test123456789"]}}**
```

Questions: How can I troubleshoot this issue? How can I see the details of the error that is being thrown?

Comment: Did you trace in the debugger where the error is thrown exactly in the library?

Comment: What is your redis server version?

Comment: Can you connect to redis server using 'redis-cli' and then execute the same command from there? I wan to verify that the stored value is actually a 'hash' and not something else like a 'list' or 'set' etc.

Comment: @SuyashGaur thank you, it was in fact NOT a hash and therefore the hgetall command wasn't working. I changed it to .get and it worked. I think the issue is that the error message was undefined so I was thrown off, I think it might be getting lost somewhere but I should be able to proceed now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, 
the **hgetall()** is not working because the datatype corresponding to the `lookup` value was not `hash`.

Changing it to **get()** has fixed the issue.